# jQuery .hide() in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, hide, show

I am testing some jQuery in Chrome/Safari and I just cant seem to solve this error. Basically, I am doing:

```
jQuery(':radio', '.some_class')
            .change(function() {
                jQuery('.special_class').show();
            })
            .blur(function() {
                jQuery('.special_class').hide();
      });
```

And I get no love at all ? Even tried

```
jQuery('.special_class').css('display','none');
```

And that aint help either - the ".some_class" shows fine but doesn't want to disappear?

**Edit: HTML Code is:**

```
<div class="some_class">
    <label for="button"><input type="radio" name="style" id="button" value="button" />Button</label>
</div>

    <div class="special_class">Hello There!</div>
```

**Edit 2:** What's even weirder is that when I "tab" - it works? but using "click" it aint?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the HTML that this code is acting on.

Answer (score 1):

The blur event doesn't mean "deselected". It means "lost keyboard focus". You will need to add some extra logic to your change event handler to detect whether the radio button was selected or deselected.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with "blur" event. Look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)

> Safari and Chrome don’t support these events on links and/or form fields in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a bit of extra css to get around this issue on one of my sites. When hiding an element, try this css (either through adding/removing an extra class with these attributes, or using jquery .css)

```
display:none; opacity:0; pointer-events:none;
```

and to show

```
display:block; opacity:1; pointer-events:auto;
```

Sometimes I also find that just display:none/block isn't enough for Safari, but this gets around it quite well.